# Should I put the SaveChanges() method of Entity Framework in a separate method or with other methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.Net Core Web API with .NET 5 and I want to consume an Entity Framework dbset. In order to add a record to the dbset, I use this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(TblPerson person)
{
    try
    {
        _context.TblPeople.Add(person);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(true);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Notice there is a `_context.SaveChanges();`. If I wanted to take that line out of the method and make it separate it would be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(TblPerson person)
{
    try
    {
        _context.TblPeople.Add(person);
        return Ok(true);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Save")]
public IActionResult Save()
{
    return Ok(_context.SaveChanges());
}
```

Now I want to see which way would be faster from client perspective if called 10 times back to back from the client.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried it? The second approach won't save your entities, as your DbContext is instantiated per request, or at least it should be, so when your client calls Save(), the earlier added entities are gone.

If you want a batch insert for performance's sake, provide a method that accepts an array.